# c programing using input() function

Tags: c

A beginner question I saw  code that was use the input() function but there was no implementation or defined or macro my question Is there a function that c already implement that her name is input and what does it do? And is there a parallel function to it? Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, there is no `input()` function unless you write it. However `input()` is commonly used as a placeholder to show where input would be taken.

Comment: I'm not ware of any `input()`-function. Functions to read in values are `scanf`, `fgets`, ...

Comment: thanks i saw now that he used lex and in lex input()  is equivalent to getchar().

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any `input()` function in C, I guess it was user defined or is just a placeholder.

There are different input functions in C, the decision which one to use depends on your needs.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9278353/6945068) answer lists some possibilities.