# How to read and print number and string using pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c-strings

I'm recollecting my C programming skills after 1 year. So I decided to start from scratch. I got stuck with this program. very grateful for help. Thanking you in advance.

Here's is my code.

```
/*Reading a number and string and printing on screen using pointers*/
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int number, *ptr,*ptr2;
char string[20];

ptr=&number;
ptr2= &string;

printf("Enter a number");
scanf("%d",&number);
printf("Enter a string");
scanf("%s", string);
printf("Your number is: %d\n", *ptr);
printf("String is %s \n", *ptr2);
}
```

It is asking for input after that it's printing number not printing string. Instead of string it's showing **Segmentation fault.**

The above program is to read and printing number and name from user. This is expecting program but it's not working properly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Post the code what you have done so far, it’s easy to follow what’s the problem is.

Comment: You forgot to show us the program

Comment: You don't say what isn't working or what you expect to happen

Comment: I just update my question. Kindly check now.

Comment: The question title is somewhat misleading. Your program does not even attempt to read n names

Comment: Thanks Michael Walz. I got the output.

Comment: Above question is to read and print a number and string from user. That's it no more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your program, `ptr2` declared as an integer pointer and you are pointing it to a `string`. `ptr2` should be of type `char *`.

In this statement:

```
ptr2= &string;
```

You don't need to give `&` operator before array name. An array name converts to a pointer that point to the initial element of the array object. So, it should be:

```
ptr2 = string;
```

If you are using `scanf` to take input string from user, make sure guard against buffer overflow. Check [this](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c).

You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int number, *ptr;
    char *ptr2;
    char string[20];

    ptr = &number;
    ptr2 = string;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", string);
    printf("Your number is: %d\n", *ptr);
    printf("String is: %s\n", ptr2);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Good to go through it once :
[Best way to get input from the user in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278226/which-is-the-best-way-to-get-input-from-user-in-c).

Comment: Thanks mate for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**1**

`ptr2` is of type int* and `string` is an array of characters.Since their types are different you can't point to `string` with `ptr2`

You have to change `ptr2`'s type to `char*`. `char* ptr2;`

**2**

Without the symbol `&` or the `sizeof` opretator an array simply converts to a pointer which points to the first element of the array.Which means `string` becomes of type `char*`.Now having both variables equal types you can do this: `ptr2 = string`;

Most new C programmers make the mistake of typing `ptr2 = &string` which is wrong.As mentioned above `string` won't convert to a pointer to the first element and `&string` type is `char(*)[]`.Again both variables must have the same type so`ptr2` could change to `char (*ptr2)[]`, but this would lead to surprising results:`ptr++` is now the size of the whole array.