# How do I edit my code so that I may output the frequency of TWO specific characters input by a user? (C Language)

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop, getchar

I have tried for hours to edit this code to work the way I want it to. I am meant to code a program to track the frequency of how often an underscore '_' and an exclamation point '!' appear in a sentence input by a user:
_Hi_there!!!

**Specifications that must be used and/or not deleted**
-This function prototype must remain unmodified:
-The getchar() method must be used to hold the value of the sentence input by the user.

Now I have this code after hours of struggling to get a proper output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int num_count;
int num_exclamation_count;
char ch;
char s[1000]; 
void count(int* num_, int* num_exclamation)
{       
    int i;
    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if((s[i] == getchar()) && (s[i] == '_'))
        {
            ++num_count;
            *num_ = num_count;  
        }
        else if((s[i] == getchar()) && (s[i] == '!'))
        {
            ++num_exclamation_count;
            *num_exclamation = num_exclamation_count;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }

}

int main (void)
{
    int num_user, num_exclamation_user;
    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    do
    {
        ch = getchar();
    }while(ch != '\n');
    count(&num_user, &num_exclamation_user);

    printf("There are %d underscores and %d exclamation points in the 
    sentence.\n", num_user, num_exclamation_user);

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is as follows:

```
There are 0 underscores and 0 exclamation points in the sentence.
```

I tried every variation of while or if or do-while statements I could conjure in my mind or find available online and I get nowhere but further away. If someone could thoroughly explain how I arrange which conditional statement/loop with the getchar() method and necessary variables, that would be awesome. Open to criticism as well if I blatantly screwed something up or passed over an obvious issue, do not be scared to hurt my feelings. I only want to learn and will be my only mindset as I am assisted with this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: The above function prototype that needed to be used for the method was: void count(int* num_, int* num_exclamation);

Comment: `char s[1000]; ` is not initialized. The first time in your loop `for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)` , s[0] will contain a random value. 2) and probably you want a single `=` here: `if((s[i] == getchar())` .

Comment: I tried your advice wildplasser and neither did any benefit. I believe in my if statements, I have an extra condition that is unnecessary I just can't tell which one or if that is even the issue..

Comment: @wildplasser Global  `char s[1000];` is initialized to zeros.

Comment: Note that `s[]` is nowhere  assigned in the entire program. And your loop `do
    {
        ch = getchar();
    }while(ch != '\n');` essentially waits for a CR to be input, ignoring everything typed in.

Comment: @chux You are correct. I'd never expected a one letter identifier for a global/static variable. ;-[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's code has these errors:

1. Not initializing `num_user, num_exclamation_user` in `main()`.  Set them to 0
2. Unneeded code of `do { ch = getchar(); while (ch != '\n');` in `main()`. Delete
3. Looking for a *null character* from input with `for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)` prevented loop iteration as `s[0]` is initialized to 0<sup>1</sup>.  User input is *lines*, not a *string*.  Look for a `'\n`'.  Also *assign* `s[i] = getchar()`, not compare `s[i] == getchar()`  [@wildplasser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917072/how-do-i-edit-my-code-so-that-i-may-output-the-frequency-of-two-specific-charact/48917346#comment84840627_48917072)

   ```
   //for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
   for (i = 0; i < 1000 && (s[i] = getchar()) != '\n'; i++) {
   ```
4. Code calls `getchar()` more than once per loop.

   ```
   // if ((s[i] == getchar()) && (s[i] == '_')) {
   if (s[i] == '_') {
     ...
   // } else if ((s[i] == getchar()) && (s[i] == '!')) {
   } else if (s[i] == '!') {
   ```

Although there are other learner issues (e.g. better to use `int ch` for input than a `char s[i]`), fixing the above will solve OP's problem.

<sup>1</sup>  *Global* integer types like the array `s[1000]` elements are initialized to 0.

Short `count()` below.  Think it out before mousing over.

> void count(int* num_, int* num_exclamation) {
>    int ch;
>    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
>      if (ch == '*') {
>
>        (*num*)++;
>      } else if (ch == '!') {
>        (*num_)++;
>      }
>    }
>  }

Answer (score 1):

your program is getting a "sentence" as user input then ignore it completely.

you are not intializing this variables.

```
int num_user;
int num_exclamation_user;
```

I'd suggest that you store the string input somewhere(e.g in `s`) like this :

```
fgets (s, 1000, stdin);
```

instead of your while do loop. 
Then in your `count` function just compare `s[i]` with `'_'` and `'!'`
like this  :

```
if(s[i] == '_'){

        ++num_count;
        *num_ = num_count;  
    }
else if (s[i] == '!')
    {
        ++num_exclamation_count;
        *num_exclamation = num_exclamation_count; 
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
```

because with `s[i] == getchar()`  you are asking the user to re-type a character.

Comment: You're right for `s[1000]` but I meant the other variables in main. I will make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

How does the string `s` get a reference to what the user has input?

You might want to insert `ch` into the string in the main loop.

```
int count = 0;
do
{
    ch = getchar();
    s[count] = ch;
    count = count + 1;
}while(ch != '\n');
```

Of course, the user shouldn't type more than 1000 characters, in which case this would fail. But, you can just add a condition in the while loop to check for `count` to fix that. In general though, you should look at using [secure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278226/which-is-the-best-way-to-get-input-from-user-in-c) input methods, which is probably outside the scope of your problem and constraints, but it is good to know.

Why have you placed `getchar()` inside the `count()` function? Do you intend to accept more characters from stdin (console)? If not, you would simply remove `getchar()` parts from that function

```
void count(int* num_, int* num_exclamation)
{       
    int i;
    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(s[i] == '_')
        {
            ++num_count;
            *num_ = num_count;  
        }
        else if(s[i] == '!')
        {
            ++num_exclamation_count;
            *num_exclamation = num_exclamation_count;
        }
        // This is not really required
        //else
        //{
        //    continue;
        //}
    }

}
```

Also, initialize `num_user` and `num_exclamation_user` in the `main()` function.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I overlooked the `'\0'` part in the for loop. I assumed `'\n'` was used in both `main()` and `count()` function.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar()` is a function that pulls the next character from the input and returns it. *Every* time you call it the next letter is retrieved.

In your code, the loop in `main()` gets the entire input and ... doesn't put it anywhere, so it is lost forever.

It seems like you are supposed to save it to `s[]`. Then, in `count()`, you can refer to the current character as `s[I]` instead of calling `getchar()`, which has no more input to return.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar()` return type is `int`, so change the `ch` type to `int` and add a check for `EOF`. Also, you don't want the `\n` character to be part of input stored in `s` array so, replace `do while` loop with `while` loop.
You don't need the globals - `num_count`, `num_exclamation_count` and `ch`. Try not to use globals as much as possible. Even you don't need the buffer `s` to be declared as a global variable. You can declare it in `main()` and pass it to function `count()` as an argument but for this, you need to modify the `count()` prototype and seems that this is something that you don't want to do.
The other answers have already pointed out the errors in your code. You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUF_SZ 1000

char s[BUF_SZ];

void count(int* num_, int* num_exclamation)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(s[i] == '_')
        {
            ++(*num_);
        }
        else if(s[i] == '!')
        {
            ++(*num_exclamation);
        }
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    int num_user = 0, num_exclamation_user = 0, i = 0, ch;

    printf("Enter a sentence: ");

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
    {
        if (i < (sizeof(s) - 1)) { // sizeof(s) - 1, to keep the space for terminating null character
            s[i++] = ch;
        } else {
            break; //discard the input beyond the size of buffer s
        }
    }

    s[i] = '\0';
    count(&num_user, &num_exclamation_user);

    printf("There are %d underscores and %d exclamation points in the sentence.\n", num_user, num_exclamation_user);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void count(int* num_, int* num_exclamation, char *ps)` looks like what a good programmer might do, but does not meet "This function prototype must remain unmodified:"

Comment: @chux: Thanks, I missed it. Made the appropriate changes.